# Could not load file or assembly "path" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, windows, service, .net-assembly, assemblyinfo

I have a service. I tried to install it using c#. Even though service file is present i got error message
`Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Sample\sample.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`
i used installutil for installation and it succeeded.

```
           string Path = @"C:\sample\sample.exe";
           string[] commandLineOptions = new string[1] { "/LogFile=install.log" };
           using (AssemblyInstaller installer = new AssemblyInstaller(Path, commandLineOptions))
            {
                installer.UseNewContext = true;
                installer.Install(null);
                installer.Commit(null);
            }
```

this code produced error
same path with installutil succeede.
I checked path, sample.exe file was present in the specified location. why this error occurs?

**Edit**

first time while run this code file is not present and exception will occure. at that time i will copy file to the specified location and same code call again.
in second time actually file exists but same error message is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after using `AssemblyInstaller` we need to unload the files.

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
                using (AssemblyInstaller installer = domain.CreateInstance(typeof(AssemblyInstaller).Assembly.FullName, typeof(AssemblyInstaller).FullName, false, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.ExactBinding, null, new Object[] { Path, new String[] { } }, null, null, null).Unwrap() as AssemblyInstaller)
                {
                    installer.UseNewContext = true;
                    installer.Install(null);
                    installer.Commit(null);
                }
                AppDomain.Unload(domain);
```

using a `AppDomain` we can unload the assembly. By this .exe file will be released after the operation